# How to embed radio form field in another radio field

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to do the following form:

## Field #1

- radio 1
- radio 2
- radio 3

  - radio 3.1
  - radio 3.2
  - ...
- radio 4

  - radio 4.1
  - radio 4.2
  - ...

When I choose radio 3, another list of radios will show up and I'll have to choose one of the children.
Is it possible to manage this kind of form field (I'm talking about the Symfony part, not the view and all the javascript event for showing up the div etc.)?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is similar to depenend form. The idea is create a listener or subscriber and attach it in the PRE_SET_DATA and SUBMIT form event where you create the other list depend of the first radio button is checked.

Maybe you can follow [this post](http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-4-dependent-forms/) to get a idea.

Comment: I think that this is not the solution because if don't have dependent form, but dependent fields.